# Django 2.1 Create Profile on User creation

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-2.0

I'm working on a project using Python(3.7) and Django(2.1) in which I need to create user's profile on user creation.

Here what I have tried:

**From `models.py`:**

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    avatar = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=1000, null=True)
    slogan = models.CharField(max_length=500, null=True)
    profile_pic = models.FileField(upload_to='media/profile_pics', null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**From `signals.py`:**

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def save_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()
```

**From `urls.py`:**

```
path('register/', views.RegisterUser.as_view(), name='register'),
```

**From `views.py`:**

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UserRegisterForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            messages.success(request, f'Account has been created for {username}!')
            form.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('login'))

        else:
            form = UserRegisterForm()
        return render(request, 'users/register.html', {'form': form})
```

**From `forms.py`:**

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'first_name',
                  'last_name', 'password1', 'password2')
```

**From `apps.py`:**

```
class JobexpertappConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'jobexpertapp'
    app_label = 'jobexpertapp'

    def ready(self):
        import jobexpertapp.signals
```

> **Update:**
>   I'm also using the facebook authentication at my site by using `django-social-auth` and to grab the facebook avatar, I have implemented 2 things, (a) defined `social_auth_pipeline.py` (b): add `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` in `settings.py`:

So,

**From `social_auth_pipeline.py`:**

```
def save_avatar(backend, user, response, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user_id=user.id)
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        profile = Profile(user_id=user.id)

    if backend.name == 'facebook':
        profile.avatar = 'http://graph.facebook.com/{}/picture?type=large'.format(response['id'])

    profile.save()
```

**From `settings.py`:**

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (

    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    # 'apps.users.pipeline.get_avatar',
    'jobexpertapp.social_auth_pipeline.save_avatar',
)
```

When I create a new account via signup page, it creates the `user` but not the profile.
Also, couldn't find any error on the console on user creation.
What can be wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do your signals.py calling?

Comment: yup, in the `apps.py` I have `import` in inside the `ready` function.

Comment: Try with removing `@receiver(post_save, sender=User)` from `save_profile`

Comment: Hi @ShafikurRahman,   Still not working!

Comment: Try this `def save_profile(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance.profile.save()` or can you check terminal is it show any logs?

Comment: still not working, the only thing in the console logs is `"POST /register/ HTTP/1.1" 302 0` which denotes the `redirect`.

Comment: try         `obj=Profile.objects.create(user=instance)` then `obj.save()`

Comment: Hi @YugandharChaudhari still not working!

Comment: Can you try assigning unique `dispatch_uid` to `@receiver(post_save, sender=User, dispatch_uid="profile creation")` [See](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/signals/#preventing-duplicate-signals)

Comment: Still not working, only the `user` has been created not the `profile`.

Comment: do we need     `if created:` ? that may hold false.

Comment: I have just print the `created` but on a new registration it doesn't printed in the console, that means it's calling the signals.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem.

My signals were in my 'users'/'apps.py' in Class UsersConfig(AppConfig):

```
def ready(self):
    import users.signals
```

What worked for me was the following. In project/'settings.py' in the INSTALLED_APPS list I used to be listing my apps with their names (i.e. 'blogs', 'users'). When I changed that and listed them like this instead:'blog.apps.BlogConfig','users.apps.UsersConfig', the profile creation/save triggering at user creation/save accordingly worked.